# How to capture ALL output from 'killall' command in a script?

Tags: bash

I originally had a 'killall' command redirect the output to a file and got this on three separate runs:

```
No matching processes belonging to you were found
kill -TERM 7370
No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

I wanted a timestamp, so I changed my script to this:

```
d=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S : ")
r=$(killall osascript 2>&1)
echo "$d$r"
exit 0
```

and now I get this (three separate runs):

```
2017-08-18 16:14:01 : No matching processes belonging to you were found
2017-08-18 16:29:01 :
2017-08-18 16:44:02 : No matching processes belonging to you were found
```

This is missing the kill -TERM nnnn detail.

How do I capture all the output?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also echo the output to the file instead

Comment: The script is being run via launchd and I redirect to the file there. Are you suggesting that the missing info will appear if I redirect inside the script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `-v, --verbose` in order to list the processes which received the issued signal. (See [man killall](https://linux.die.net/man/1/killall))

> -v, --verbose
>
> Report if the signal was successfully sent.

Hence, your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
d=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S : ")
r=$(killall -v osascript 2>&1)
echo "$d$r"
exit 0
```

Replacing `osascript` with `sleep` gives me the following output:

```
2017-08-21 17:14:30 : Killed sleep(12493) with signal 15
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made the change. Waiting for osascript to misbehave and stay running after script finishes, which it does randomly (hence the need to kill it). I run the kill 1 minute before running the main script, which runs every 15 minutes.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.